# Enriching categories of simplicial objects

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, monoidal-categories, model-categories

Let $C$ be a cocomplete category and $Simp(C)=C^{\triangle^{op}}$ the category of simplicial objects in $C$. I want to show that $Simp(C)$ is simplicially enriched but I don't understand how the enrichemt supposed to look. Here's what I tried:

Let $X_{\bullet},Y_{\bullet} \in Simp(C)$. The end formula gives $Nat(X_{\bullet},Y_{\bullet})= \int_{n \in \triangle^{op}} C(X_n,Y_n)$. But I have no idea why this is a simplicial set. It looks like a set to me.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to "show that $Simp(C)$ is simplicially enriched": a simplicial enrichment is an extra _structure_ you can put on a category (and there might be many different ways to do so), and every category can be made simplicially enriched by just replacing the Hom-sets with the corresponding constant simplicial sets.  Presumably in this context you want the simplicial enrichment to have some additional useful properties.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, sorry. I want it to be tensored as well. I'd like to see at least one example to enrich this in a natural way. Hopefully that would pull me out of the confusion.

Comment: More precisely, if $D$ is an ordinary category, I would say a simplicial enrichment of $D$ is a category $\mathbf{D}$ enriched in simplicial sets together with an equivalence between $D$ and the ordinary category obtained from $\mathbf{D}$ by taking the $0$th set of each Hom-simplicial set.  So it doesn't really make sense to say an ordinary category "is" simplicially enriched: the simplicially enriched category is a new, different object, that has a certain relationship with the original category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard simplicial enrichment on $Simp(C)$ is defined as follows.  First, note that since $C$ is cocomplete, it can be considered to be tensored over $Set$: If $X$ is an object of $C$ and $S$ is a set, then $X\otimes S$ is a coproduct of copies of $X$ indexed by elements of the set $S$.  If $K$ is a simplicial set and $A$ is an object of $Simp(C)$, we can define now define an object $A\otimes K$ of $Simp(C)$ by $$(A\otimes K)_n=A_n\otimes K_n,$$
where $A_n\otimes K_n$ is defined as above (the coproduct of copies of $A_n$ indexed by elements of $K_n$).  The structure maps of the simplicial object $A\otimes K$ are defined in the obvious way (a map $n\to m$ in $\Delta$ gives maps $A_m\to A_n$ and $K_m\to K_n$, which induce a map $A_m\otimes K_m\to A_n\otimes K_n$).

This tensor operation can then be used to define a simplicially enriched category whose objects are the objects of $Simp(C)$: given two such objects $A$ and $B$, the Hom-simplicial set $\mathbf{Hom}(A,B)$ is defined by $$\mathbf{Hom}(A,B)_n=\operatorname{Nat}(A\otimes \Delta^n,B).$$

Of course, there are various details to be checked here to verify that this all makes sense and really gives a tensored simplicially enriched category, but they should all be pretty straightforward.

Comment: What I did just now is to define $X_{\bullet} \otimes \triangle^n = \int_{k \in \triangle^{op}} \triangle^{op}(k,n) \cdot X_n$. Then everything else follows. Is that correct? That seems to be the reason you need cocompleteness.

Comment: Unless I'm being dumb, that definition doesn't seem quite right: isn't the right-hand side just an object of $C$, not a simplicial object?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Anyway yor answer is perfect. Thanks!